# Programmatically enable (or disable) AppleScript support for an application

Tags: cocoa, applescript, cocoa-scripting

I have an App Store app in which the free version is not scriptable, but the premium version is. AppleScript support is one of the key differences. I know the App Store reviewers are pushing more and more towards free + in-app-purchase, which will help declutter the App Store. Fine, I'll play ball.

Now I need to do something programmatically that I've always just worked into the build.

- Is there a way to *disable* AppleScript if my `OSAScriptingDefinition` and `NSAppleScriptEnabled` are set in my `Info.plist`? This would still allow people to open the dictionary, and maybe they'd like what they see and consider activating the upgrade. Or,
- Is there a way to enable AppleScript *after* the fact? Obviously with code-signing, I can't do things like modify Info.plist, or add my SDEF to the bundle later. But maybe if the SDEF were in a non-standard location, I could load it from the bundle and tell the system about it manually.

Does the SDEF *have* to live in my bundle? If not, I'm not sure how to point to the user's Application Support directory in the sandbox. I've also considered xinclude an SDEF I can install after the fact, but again, the SDEF and plist require actual directory paths and not functions.

I've tried a couple of things such as attempting to set NSScriptSuiteRegistry's singleton to nil, to no effect.

Because `OSAScriptingDefinition` and `NSAppleScriptEnabled` enable "automatic" support, surely there must be a manual way to make them to effect if not in the plist, and hopefully with a public API.

Any ideas here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A few points, for orientation:

- All AppleScript commands are subclasses of `NSScriptCommand`
- All AppleScript objects are represented by subclasses of
  `NSScriptObjectSpecifier`
- The scriptability of an app is controlled by its shared instance of `NSScriptSuiteRegistry`

This gives you a few options. You could try, for instance, overriding `NSScriptSuiteRegistry setSharedScriptSuiteRegistry:` and setting it to nil for the free version. You could also write a category on `NSScriptCommand` and/or `NSScriptObjectSpecifier` that does a version check. That would give you fine-grained control: you could call it from any methods that handle a script command or returns a script object, and decide on the fly which you want to allow and which you want to block; maybe even pop up a 'Pay for Full AppleScript Access' dialog.

Comment: I can't seem to get the application to use my `NSScriptSuiteRegistry` subclass. Even if I create the singleton `MyScriptSuiteRegistry` in the app controller's -init, the real `NSScriptSuiteRegistry` is being created and used, which is a shame, because I like this approach.

Comment: I don't think you need to create it, just call it sometime after the app loads. In other words, let it load its script registry normally, and then call `[NSScriptSuiteRegistry setSharedScriptSuiteRegistry:nil]` if the app is in 'free version' state.

Comment: If it's like some of Cocoa's other singletons, I have to instantiate a subclass before the default instance is created -- there's not really a legal way to override the method without subclassing. I could swizzle, but I still don't have access to the ivar that I'd have to make nil.

Comment: It seems to me that cocoa scripting automatically creates his singleton; it would have to, otherwise cocoa scripting wouldn't work at all. Of course, I'm not sure *when* it creates it — if might not be available till after `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` — but as I remember you don't have to do anything special once you've enabled scripting support. Maybe set a breakpoint on `setSharedScriptSuiteRegistry` and see where the app calls it.

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue, Cocoa creates it automatically. If it were, say, NSDocumentController, I could instantiate a subclass before the Cocoa-instantiated one, and it would be my NSDocumentController. Cocoa wouldn't create another.

Comment: It turns out, this is really easy, and you pointed out the way. If you post an answer, I'll accept it: `NSAppleScriptEnabled` in the Info.plist triggers the creation of the singleton; if I leave out the plist setting and _never_ make a reference to `[NSScriptSuiteRegistry sharedScriptSuiteRegistry]`, then my SDEF is effectively ignored. As soon as I make a reference to the singleton, though, it's created, and I can use what's defined in the SDEF. This solves the problem for me.

Comment: Not sure if it was buffering or not, but the above statement is incorrect. In any case, instantiating my subclass and overriding `loadSuitesFromBundle` to do nothing solved the issue for me.

Comment: Yeah, that surprised me when you said it worked. I really think you need to set up your app for scriptability and then block it in runtime through one of the methods I suggested.

Comment: Can you modify your answer to recommend the loadSuitesFromBundle? I hate to leave something unanswered, and I hate to not give credit where it's due, because ultimately your answer (in the current form) led me to where I needed to be.

Answer (score 1):

CocoaScripting is a black box and not very adaptable. Simplest (kludgy) solution would be to wait until CS has installed its Apple event handlers then call `-[NSAppleEventManager setEventHandler:andSelector:forEventClass:andEventID:]` to replace those with a dummy handler that always sends back a "requires in-app purchase" error. (Don’t replace the standard `open`, `quit`, etc. handlers obviously.)

Comment: A lot of the functionality is via AppleScript properties, though, and it looks like CocoaScripting is using KVC directly to access those.

Comment: You’ll need to replace CS’s `get` (core/getd) and `set` (core/setd) handlers as well.